# Rodrigues function in Python version opencv not working

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I want to use python version opencv function Rodrigues() to convert rotation matrix to the rotation vector. The rotMat to be converted is

```
 [[ 0.59966056 -0.59966056  0.52991926]
 [ 0.70710678  0.70710678  0.        ]
 [-0.37470951  0.37470951  0.8480481 ]]
```

and the code I wrote is something like

```
rotVec = np.zeros((1, 3), np.float32)
cv2.Rodrigues(rotMat, rotVec)
```

Which follows the documentation like
[image]
But it turns out that the result is all 0 and the function is not working. 
I am very new to python and I am appreciated if someone could point out error.

Answer (score 5):

Your function call isn't quite correct; you do need to handle both return arguments, even if you ignore one.  These calls should work for you: `rotVec,_ = cv2.Rodrigues(rotMat)` or `cv2.Rodrigues2(rotMat,rotVec, jacb)`

Comment: it answers exactly what he is asking for. he is calling the function in the wrong way, that's why I telling him the correct way to use it. not sure why this isn't considered an answer

Comment: I read it a little too fast; my apologies.  A bit more wording would help; I'm usually looking for a definitive, tutorial response.  I think I got triggered by the word "try".  We prefer to explain to the OP *why* the solution works.  I edited your response in what I hope is a productive way; I invite you to improve my attempt.